# Get a nanosecond-precise atime, mtime, ctime fields for file (stat?)

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, stat

Some filesystems (e.g. ext4 and JFS) offer nanosecond resolution of atime/mtime fields. How can I read ns-resolution fields? The [`stat` syscall](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat64.2.html) returns `time_t` which is a second-resolution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The second-resolution times are in the fields:

```
           time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
           time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
           time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
```

But "NOTES" section of the man http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html says:

> Since kernel 2.5.48, the stat structure supports nanosecond resolution for the    three file timestamp fields.  Glibc exposes the nanosecond component of each
>          field using names of the form st_atim.tv_nsec if the _BSD_SOURCE or
>          _SVID_SOURCE feature test macro is defined.  These fields are specified in
>          POSIX.1-2008, and, starting with version 2.12, glibc also exposes these field
>          names if _POSIX_C_SOURCE is defined with the value 200809L or greater, or
>          _XOPEN_SOURCE is defined with the value 700 or greater.  If none of the
>          aforementioned macros are defined, then the nanosecond values are exposed with
>          names of the form st_atimensec.

So, nsec parts of times are  in the same "struct stat": ( /usr/include/asm/stat.h )

```
 unsigned long st_atime_nsec;

 unsigned int st_mtime_nsec;

 unsigned long st_ctime_nsec;

 #define STAT_HAVE_NSEC 1
```

Comment: So, if I want my program to be portable, which one should I use: `st_atim.tv_nsec` or `st_atimensec`?

Comment: How to make it compatible with the NetBSD and OSX specific implementations *(which support nanosecond but with different types ad names)*?