# Get file modification time to nanosecond precision

Tags: python, linux, datetime, precision, high-resolution-time

I need to get the full nanosecond-precision modified timestamp for each file in a Python 2 program that walks the filesystem tree. I want to do this in Python itself, because spawning a new subprocess for every file will be slow.

From the C library on Linux, [you can get nanosecond-precision timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206014/get-a-nanosecond-precise-atime-mtime-ctime-fields-for-file-stat) by looking at the `st_mtime_nsec` field of a `stat` result. For example:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    struct stat stat_result;
    if(!lstat("/", &stat_result)) {
        printf("mtime = %lu.%lu\n", stat_result.st_mtim.tv_sec, stat_result.st_mtim.tv_nsec);
    } else {
        printf("error\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

prints `mtime = 1380667414.213703287` (`/` is on an ext4 filesystem, which supports nanosecond timestamps, and the clock is UTC).

Similarly, `date --rfc-3339=ns --reference=/` prints `2013-10-01 22:43:34.213703287+00:00`.

Python (2.7.3)'s `os.path.getmtime(filename)` and `os.lstat(filename).st_mtime` give the mtime as a `float`. However, the result is wrong:

```
In [1]: import os
In [2]: os.path.getmtime('/') % 1
Out[2]: 0.21370339393615723
In [3]: os.lstat('/').st_mtime % 1
Out[3]: 0.21370339393615723
```

—only the first 6 digits are correct, presumably due to floating-point error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively you coudl use the [cffi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cffi) library which works with Python 2 with the follwoing code (*tested on LInux*):

```
from __future__ import print_function

from cffi import FFI

ffi = FFI()
ffi.cdef("""
typedef long long time_t;

typedef struct timespec {
    time_t   tv_sec;
    long     tv_nsec;
    ...;
};

typedef struct stat {
    struct timespec st_mtim;
    ...;
};

int lstat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
""")

C = ffi.verify()

result = ffi.new("struct stat *")
p = C.lstat("foo.txt", result)
print("mtime = {0:d}.{1:09d}".format(result.st_mtim.tv_sec, result.st_mtim.tv_nsec))
```

This is identical in behavior to your C program in your question.
This produces the output:

```
$ ./test.py
mtime = 1381711568.315075616
```

Which has the same precision as your C program:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
$ ./test
mtime = 1381711568.315075616
```

Comment: `{1:d}` should be `{1:09d}`.

Comment: I'm not sure that makes a terrible lot of difference :) But I'll modify it anyway :)

Comment: Try `import os; open('/tmp/a.tmp','w').close(); os.utime('/tmp/a.tmp', (1.0001, 1.001)); stat = ffi.new('struct stat *'); print(os.path.getmtime('/tmp/a.tmp')); c.stat('/tmp/a.tmp', stat); print('{}.{}'.format(stat.st_mtim.tv_sec, stat.st_mtim.tv_nsec))`

Answer (score 10):

`os.stat('/').st_mtime` is a float object, and the precision of float is too low for a timestamp with nanosecond,

> Python’s underlying type for floats is an IEEE 754 double, which is
>   only good for about 16 decimal digits. With ten digits before the
>   decimal point, that leaves six for sub-second resolutions, which is
>   three short of the range required to preserve POSIX
>   nanosecond-resolution timestamps. via: [This Week in Python Stupidity: os.stat, os.utime and Sub-Second Timestamps](http://ciaranm.wordpress.com/2009/11/15/this-week-in-python-stupidity-os-stat-os-utime-and-sub-second-timestamps/)

If you can use Python 3, there's a new a attribute called `st_mtime_ns`, which is st_mtime in nanoseconds. try it.

```
>>> os.stat('.').st_mtime
1381571932.044594
>>> os.stat('.').st_mtime_ns
1381571932044593972
```

References:

[PEP 410 -- Use decimal.Decimal type for timestamps](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0410/)

[os.stat(): add new fields to get timestamps as Decimal objects with nanosecond resolution](http://bugs.python.org/issue11457)

[add st_*time_ns fields to os.stat(), add ns keyword to os.*utime*(), os.*utimens*() expects a number of nanoseconds](http://bugs.python.org/issue14127)

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say the same as glasslion -- Python converts st_mtime to floating point, which loses significant digits.

One alternative is to use the "ctypes" module, or cython, to access the C library directly, which should return a nice unsigned long in the nanosecond field, (can't give you an example because you didn't give any information about your operating system).